# Mysql query where value is more than a specific entity value

Tags: mysql

```
TableA:
------
id | property|
--------------
1  |  0      |
2  |  5      |
3  |  6      |
```

Is it possible to query in mysql in single command to figure out which has a property value more than that `where id=2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the `property` value for `id=2`, and compare to that. The subquery must return just one row, which is the case here.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE property > (SELECT property FROM TableA WHERE id = 2)
```